# Jquery replace not working over the entire input text

Tags: javascript

I have a text box on a HTML page, the idea is that the user can enter any text into the box and then Jquery will remove every other than letters of the alphabet.

This is what I have come up with, it works for small text samples, 1-2 lines, however anything over this it only works on a small section of the input text, is there a better way to do this?

```
$("#read").change(function () {
    read = $("#read").val().toLowerCase().replace(/[^a-z]+/, '');
    $("#read").val(read);
});
```

Comment: `replace()` is not a jquery method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add /gi to end of your regular expression

```
/[^a-z]+/gi
```

then it will replace all occurrences through whole string.

g (for global) and i (for ignore case)

with the comments of @Lunar this is how your code should look like

```
$("#read").change(function () {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/gi, ''));
   });
```

Comment: @Lunar Notice that the `i` flag ignores case, so you don't need `toLowerCase()` unless you want your output to be in lowercase.

Comment: @Lunar Also, just use `this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, '')`. There really is no need for all that jQuery in the function body. Also note that the `+` is unnecessary since you have set `g` anyway (though it also doesn't hurt to have it).

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the regex's global flag, so that it will replace *all* matches instead of just the *first* match.

```
/[^a-z]+/ig
```

[More about JS regular expressions.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)